# Why does the role claim have incorrect type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I downloaded the WebApp-RoleClaims-DotNet sample application and somehow cannot get it to work.

The about page has the following rather straightforward piece of code:

```
        ClaimsIdentity claimsId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var appRoles = new List<String>();
        foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindAll(claimsId.RoleClaimType))
            appRoles.Add(claim.Value);
        ViewData["appRoles"] = appRoles;
        return View();
```

Now, the expression `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindAll(claimsId.RoleClaimType)` returns an empty list, even though I have proper roles assigned.

This is I guess, because -- according to the debugger -- the role claim have the type `roles` instead of the proper namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hey Gabor - the line [here](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-RoleClaims-DotNet/blob/master/WebApp-RoleClaims-DotNet/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L56) should set the RoleClaimType property to "roles" so that this chunk of code works and so that the Authorize tags work on the controllers.  Is that not the case? Does the debugger resolve the RoleClaimType to the namespace form you listed above?

Comment: Hey Dstrockis, thanks a lot! I commented out that whole block, because I was configuring for a single tenant application. Would never have spotted that line, even though it was right in front of me.

Comment: Right on. We're working on shipping a fix to the middleware that should remove the need for that line at all.

Comment: This worked for me ; https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/03/09/azure-app-service-authentication-app-roles/

Comment: Oops! I posted an answer without reading all the comments. Again!

Answer (score 0):

did you ever get this working?

I found this worked:

```
        ClaimsIdentity id = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var appRoles = new List<string>();

        foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
        {
            appRoles.Add(claim.Value);
        }
```

I hope it helps someone with a similar problem.