# Multi Tenant Azure AD non admin login

Tags: security, authentication, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an existing web app which I am trying to add Office 365 integration. I want all users to be able to log in with OAuth2, and admin users to be able to read users from the directory.

So I created an Azure AD app, and granted the "Enable sign-on and read users profiles" and "Read directory data" delegate permissions.

When an O365 admin user logs in, it works as expected. But when a O365 non-admin user logs in, they get the error "AADSTS90093: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions.".

After much trial and error (the docs are anything but clear), I figured that I need to append prompt=admin_consent to the auth url. By appending this to the auth URL, if I log in with an admin, then subsequent non-admin logins work as expected.

The problem is, that I don't know whether the user about to click the "Login with Office 365" button on my login page is an admin or not. It seems that the first person who logs into the app from the O365 domain MUST be a O365 admin, AND the auth url MUST have prompt=admin_consent. If a non-admin tries to login BEFORE an admin does, then they get the AADSTS90093 error, and there doesn't seem to be any way for my app to gracefully handle this scenario. Even worse - they can't log in at all.

What I really need here, is to have 1 login button, that will log non-admin users in but without access to the directory, and will log admin users in with access to the directory, but this doesn't seem to be possible. Google have the concept of scopes, but this seems absent from Microsofts implementation.

I see 2 potential solutions, neither of which are great:

1. Add a checkbox on the login page labelled "Log in as Office 365 Administrator". If this is checked, then I append the prompt=admin_consent to the auth url. The problem with this (aside from cluttering up my login page), is that it doesn't cater for non-admins trying to log in before an admin has. So most users still aren't able to log in - not great.
2. Create 2 Azure AD apps. One with both "Enable sign-on and read users profiles" and "Read directory data" permissions, and the other with just the "Enable sign-on and read users profiles" permission. The login page is linked to the first app, which would allow both admin and non-admin users to log in at any time. Then, on a config page in my app, I have an option to "Complete integration with O365", which presents a link to authenticate with the 2nd AAD app. This way, I can guarantee all users can perform basic log in, and I can integrate with the directory and calendar when an admin clicks the 2nd button. The downside of this, is that even if the first user to log in is an o365 admin, I won't be able to access the directory until the second auth has been completed. And secondly, my app will appear twice in the customers AAD applications list.

It seems like I am trying to achieve such a trivial thing here - to be able to log all users in, but if an admin logs in then they can access the directory. So how do you achieve this with AAD apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution #1 is the one we recommend in our samples, take for example https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet and the sign up controllers. As of today consent in Azure AD is an "all-or-nothing" package deal, hence apps that require admin consent must be first approved by an administrator. We are working on making the consent dynamic, thanks to which you'll be able to sign in non-admin users without directory querying powers and defer that ability until an admin grants consent - but that's still quite some time out hence for the time being #1 is the supported approach.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. If we go with solution #1, then the majority of users will not be able to log in to the app until an admin user logs in first. This is not a viable solution for us. Is there a reason other than those listed above not to go with solution #2?

Comment: Using multiple identities for the same web app is not something the auth libraries have been designed for. You'll need to dig heavily in the extensibility points to do just in time clientID substitutions, you'll have different session identifiers, you'll have incompatible token caches, and so on... I cannot guarantee it will work reliably. And of course, there's the administrative overhead you hinted at. Your scenario is absolutely valid, which is why we are working on dynamic consent, however that's not a small change (the current model has deep roots in the system) hence it will take time

Comment: My application is written in python, so I am not using any of the .net libs. I think I'll give it a try today and see how it goes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GwynHowell Why can't it be as intuitive as "ask user for consent if not consented yet"? Right now the user experience is that, you get an error, then you have to make a special query so that it will ask you for consent and then you can go back and log-in.

Comment: Because you cannot have a single aad app which allows both non admins and admins to log in. I worked around the limitation, by creating 2 separate aad apps with different permissions - one for non admins and the other for admins.

Comment: Thanks GwynHowell for the answer. I meant to tag @vibronet for my question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

if your app requests permissions that requires tenant admin consent, then only a tenant admin can actually grant those permissions, and thus you will see errors like the one you are having.

You can resolve your issues by reducing the permissions requested by your application to only those which a normal user can consent to.

Also make sure you are not passing the query parameter "&prompt=admin_consent" as this can only be done by an admin.

https://www.gittprogram.com/question/3306112_aadsts90093-calling-principal-cannot-consent-due-to-lack-of-permissions.html