# How to fix " AADSTS90094: This application requires application permissions to another application" error after giving admin consent

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, adal, adal.js

I recently requested new application permissions in my multi-tenanted Azure AD App so that I can access the Graph API. I'm using `adal.js` to authentication users in a web app, while the actual requests to Graph are made on a node server using `adal-node` and a certificate.

The new permissions work. I'm able to access Graph using application permissions, and have not had any issues with node server.

The problem is that now whenever admins login to the web app (using `adal.js), they get presented with the consent screen, no matter how many times they consent. Non-admin users are presented with the "Need Admin Approval" screen whenever they login, stopping them from being able to login at all.

I've tried this across different tenancies with the same results. I've also tried approving the permissions through `azure.portal.com` and removing the app entirely from a tenancy and approving them again.

I've also tried taking away the new permissions and reverting to the old permissions. No matter what, users are hitting the "Need admin approval" screen.

#### User login code

```
public login(): void {
  this.adalContext.login();
}
```

#### Admin login code

```
public adminLogin(): void {
  this.adalContext.config.displayCall = (urlNavigate) => {
    let url = urlNavigate + "&prompt=admin_consent";
    this.adalContext.promptUser(url);
  };
  this.adalContext.login();
}
```

To be clear, this app had been running fine for **over a month**. It's only once I changed the permissions that this began happening.

Comment: @RohitSaigal I think that refers to the Microsoft API's I'm asking permission to. Regardless, I found the answer in a different StackOverflow question and posted it below.

Comment: ok makes sense.. I took it out once I saw your answer posted at almost the same time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question ended up helping me: [Why Azure AD fails to login non-admins in multi-tenant scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791557/why-azure-ad-fails-to-login-non-admins-in-multi-tenant-scenario?rq=1)

Since I was requesting **only** application permissions, Azure AD defaults to always asking for consent whenever a user logs in. Once I added one **delegated** permission (`Microsoft.Graph.User.Read`), the consent prompt disappeared.

I must have accidentally missed this permission while going through the process of adding and removing them during my troubleshooting.