# User is prompted to consent to the application on every sign in - Azure AD v2.0

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a native app (Electron) where I have integrated Azure AD v2.0 Sign in experience. We have only enabled Microsoft Account based sign in for now.

Here's my sign in URL looks like:

```
const url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<my-application-id>&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')}&scope=openid%20profile%20email&response_mode=fragment&nonce=<some-random-value&state=<some-random-value>`;
```

Using this link, a user can sign in successfully. There're no issues there. However every time a user signs in, they are presented with a consent dialog after providing their credentials.

Based on my knowledge, if a user has consented to an app and there're no change in the permissions (rather scopes) asked by the app, then the user should not be prompted to consent again.

I'm wondering why this is happening. I even tried with appending `prompt=login` to the URL but that has no effect.

Is there another setting that I need to make? I looked at both the old portal (Microsoft Application Registration Portal) as well as new portal (App Registration (Preview) in Azure Portal) but could not find a setting that will disable the consent prompt on every sign in.

Comment: please collect the actual http url to the /authorize endpoint and share please.

Comment: What do you mean by actual URL? I’ve shared the URL I’m using.

Comment: Its in your code, its quiet often that what actual gets executed has been munged by the SDK you might be using. That's why i advise folks to check what actually got executed at the network layer using a tool like fiddler

Comment: Thanks Kalyan. I am not using any SDK. I am simply redirected the user to the following URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=openid%20profile%20email&response_mode=fragment&nonce=1553867671950&state=12345`. As mentioned in my post, the sign in works perfectly fine. It's the consent prompt that gets shown every time is bothering me.

Comment: use the [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to check if the consent to the permission is being recorded? (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/OAuth2PermissionGrants)

Comment: change "response_type=id_token" to "response_type=code+id_token" and try it as well

Comment: Can you provide some more instructions on using the Graph Explorer. What I need to check? I will also try code+id_token thing.

Comment: So I tried code+id_token and that didn't help. Please let me know what I need to check in Graph Explorer. I checked https://account.live.com/consent/Manage and it tells me that I have already consented to the application.

Comment: I see you already have some good suggestions from Kalyan Krishna.. Please check one more thing.. I've seen posts before mentioning such behavior when app registration only had application permissions (and no delegated permissions at all).. so when users try to sign in, it tries to go towards admin consent.. Here's one old thread with some pointers.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791557/why-azure-ad-fails-to-login-non-admins-in-multi-tenant-scenario?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Rohit. So the issue is not with signing in the users. That works perfectly fine. It's the prompt for consent that's bothering. The link you shared is more geared towards Azure AD users. In my case, it is always users with Personal Microsoft Account.

Comment: ok makes sense Gaurav.. I didn't notice the MSA part.. btw.. I know there is a setting in Azure AD under user settings where administrator can disable user consent and make it mandatory that only Admins can do consent.. I wonder if there's anything similar that applies for personal accounts..

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is due to the fact that you are using a reply URL with a scheme that is not "http" or "https" ("urn", in your case). In this situation, Microsoft Accounts will ask the user to confirm the the delegated permissions the app is requesting, even if these permissions have been granted previously. This additional prompt helps make sure users know which app the app is identifying as.

In most native client app scenarios, this should not be a significant issue. It will add an extra step during the initial sign-in to the app, but after that, the app should be able to make use of the refresh token for most token acquisitions. (Occasionally, the app may need to trigger an interactive sign-in again, but this would be relatively rare.)

If you look *very* closely, you'll notice a slight difference between the initial consent prompt ("...needs your permission to..."), and the subsequent confirmation prompt ("... needs you to confirm its permission to...").

[image: Initial consent prompt "MY APP needs your permission"]
[image: Subsequent consent prompt "MY APP needs you to confirm its permission"]

Comment: Thanks Philippe! Very interesting observation about the confirmation prompt. Let me confirm it on my end as well. So if I don't use `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` and instead use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`, I should not see the consent prompt. Correct?

Comment: So I checked the confirmation prompt and you're correct! However I changed the redirect URI to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient` from `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` but I am still getting prompt for consent (getting the 2nd prompt .... "need to you confirm" one though). Can you please explain why that is happening?